# how to specify a range in vba using a cell value in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to vba and basically only use it when amending a range value (having previously recorded the script using a macro in excel). Since I add/delete rows in excel I have to go to the vba script and manually update the range part. So if my range on the excel sheet has expanded from A2:R83 to A2.R84 heres one of the parts I update from:

`Range("A2:R83").Select`

To:

`Range("A2:R84").Select`

Is there a way I can specify a cell that vba can take the range values from? eg can I, on the excel sheet cell **X1** input **A2** and in cell **Y2** input **R84** and have the vba script reference these cells to determine the current range?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want, :

```
Sub test()
  Dim s1 As String, s2 As String

  s1 = Sheet1.Range("A1"): s2 = Sheet1.Range("B1")

  Range(s1 & ":" & s2).Select
End Sub
```

You will, however, run into trouble if the values in A1 and B1 are not valid cell-names, so some input validation may be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly!! yes I do understand that it can be an issue if the values are not valid but it will take just a sec or so to update these than the script itself. The full basic code now looks like:    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String


  s1 = Sheet1.Range("F1"): s2 = Sheet1.Range("G1")

   
    Range(s1 & ":" & s2).Select
    With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, _
        "C:\Users\jim\Desktop\macrotest.mht", "Sheet1", s1 & ":" & s2, _
        xlHtmlStatic, "macrotest_26340", "")
        .Publish (True)
        .AutoRepublish = False
    End With
End Sub

Answer (score 1):

I found that it is possible to make the validation range dinamic using INDIRECT.

1.- In location that you choose (in the example I use X1 in sheet1) put

```
="'Sheet1'!"&"A2:"&"R"&COUNTA(R1:R2000)
```

I put R2000 to have plenty space in case the range grows, change to a size that suits you. The result of this formula will be a range. Its size will change every time you put something new in R because of the `Counta`.

2.- In the validation section place this formula when you record it.

```
=INDIRECT('Sheet'!$X$1)
```

This makes the validation read the range based on what x1 says.

Answer (score 0):

This will figure your range,

```
Sub SelectRng()
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range

    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(Rws, "R"))


    Rng.Select    'or whatever you want to do with it.


End Sub
```